# Problems with ScaleGestureDetector.IOnScaleGestureListener C# Xamarin

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm building an app, that allows the user to move 2 textviews in Xamarin android .net.
Everything works as it should, exept for onScale (pinch gesture). Debug shows that IOnScaleGestureListener functions are never called(that's why i left them empty). Does anyone know what do i need to do to call them?
main activity

```
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, IOnTouchListener, IOnGestureListener, ScaleGestureDetector.IOnScaleGestureListener 
    {
        int position = 0;
        private List<TextView> txtGestureView = new List<TextView>();
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lps = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400);
            txtGestureView.Add(FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.imageView));
            txtGestureView.Add(FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.imageView2));
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.relativeLayout1);
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
            scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, this);
            txtGestureView[0].SetOnTouchListener(this);
            txtGestureView[0].Tag = "0";
            txtGestureView[1].SetOnTouchListener(this);
            txtGestureView[1].Tag = "1";
        }
        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            position = int.Parse(v.Tag.ToString(), 0);
            return gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }
        public bool OnScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
        {
            float diffY = e2.GetY() - e1.GetY();
            float diffX = e2.GetX() - e1.GetX();
            txtGestureView[position].SetX(txtGestureView[position].GetX() + diffX);
            txtGestureView[position].SetY(txtGestureView[position].GetY() + diffY);
            return true;
        }
        public bool OnDown(MotionEvent e) { return true; }
        public bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) { return true; }
        public void OnLongPress(MotionEvent e) { }
        public void OnShowPress(MotionEvent e) { }
        public bool OnSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) { return true; }

        public bool OnScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool OnScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void OnScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {

        }
    }
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
                android:layout_width="match_parent"  
                android:layout_height="match_parent"    
                tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">    
    
                 <TextView    
                android:id="@+id/imageView"    
                android:layout_width="200dp"    
                android:text="imageView"    
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="35dp"    
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"      
                android:background="@android:color/black"    
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"    
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>   
    
                 <TextView    
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"    
                android:layout_width="200dp"    
                android:text="imageView2"    
                android:textSize="35dp"    
                android:gravity="center"    
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"    
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"    
                android:background="@android:color/black"    
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `IOnScaleGestureListener`? This event fires when user scales the view by using pinch gestures. Plase check it.

Comment: I want to scale those textviews by using pinch gestures. I thought that they will be invoked when i touch the screen with two fingers, and in result give me some value of scaling in one of these functions.

Comment: Do you mean when you touch the screen with two fingers, it would not file the `OnScale` method? But it files the `OnScroll`? I would check it again.

Comment: Exactly, and i want to fire the onScale method when using two fingers.

Comment: Even when i unhook the GestureDetector from activity the functions from ScaleGestureDetector do not fire.

Comment: Found what was wrong, i was returning gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e) in OnTouch() insted of scaleDetector.OnTouchEvent(e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `OnTouch()`
i was returning
`return gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);`
instead of
`return scaleDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);`

what's why non of this functions:

```
        public bool OnScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool OnScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void OnScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {

        }
```

were called.